# React Router where to use AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a project using [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router), and I'm having some problems with the data flow.

On every page there is an AJAX call that gets the data for the component. I have been putting them in `componentDidMount`:

```
// Below code is written in ES6
componentDidMount(){
  $.get(someURL, (data)=>{
    this.setState({data:data})
  })
}
```

Although this works on initial load, it does not get called again when the url changes (a manual refresh is needed). I cannot seem to find a proper [life cycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) to place the AJAX calls.

Someone please enlighten me with the proper approach to getting data in React Router.

Comment: I know, this is old but.. check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279786/react-router-where-to-use-ajax

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After a bit of searching around, [this README](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v1.0.0-beta3/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#dynamic-segments-keys-and-lifecycle-methods) ultimately solves the problem.

There are 2 solutions outlined in the document:

1. Use `addHandlerKey={true}`:

   `<Route handler={User} path="/user/:userId" addHandlerKey={true} />`
2. Use `componentWillReceiveProps` instead of `componentDidMount`.

   - I ended up using both, `componentDidMount` for the initial load, `componentWillReceiveProps` for subsequent ones.
   - Since they share the same code, I created a new function `_updateState` and called it in both lifecycles.

---

My code now:

```
class Classes extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){ this._updateState() }
  componentWillReceiveProps(){ this._updateState() }
  _updateState(){
    $.get(/*Some URL*/, (data)=>{
      this.setState({data:data})
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: you can fire the ajax on componentWillMount lifeCycle handler

Comment: The `README` link is now broken.